# Deploying Polymer site on Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting

I am a beginner in Polymer and Firebase.
I did every step that [Polymer Setup](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/psk/set-up.html) and [Firebase Setup](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/quickstart.html) instructions said but when I deploy the site on Firebase, I get completely different sites.

Also the navigation is distorted.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Below is the way the site appears on Firebase after being deployed.
[image: website deployed on Firebase]

Below is the way the site appears on localhost after being deployed.
[image]

Comment: What errors, if any, are you seeing in the console? This is likely a path issue.

Comment: @DavidEast there are no errors, just that it is completely projecting something different when deployed on Firebase

Comment: It is a known problem in the process of the dist creation during vulcanization somewhere, check Github PSK page and the last issues!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/550 and related issues.
Be sure then to use the latest version of everything!

Comment: Still there's no solution.